# button is not getting clicked with puppeteer selenium

Tags: puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless : false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.thegoodlifespace.com/adidas-by-pharrell-williams-superstar-primeknit-s42928.html');
  
  
  
  await page.waitForNavigation();

  await page.click("#product-addtocart-button");

  
 
})();
```

i am tring to add to cart but it is not working i need the page to fully load then to click on the button but it seems like it is not working, can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is the button appear first but it is disabled until a size div(UK 7.5) appear then it become enable, so you must wait first for this div then wait for the button, this code work for me it should work for you too

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.thegoodlifespace.com/adidas-by-pharrell-williams-superstar-primeknit-s42928.html');
  await page.waitForSelector("#option-label-adidas_size-173-item-77")
  await page.waitForSelector("#product-addtocart-button")
  const target = await page.$("#product-addtocart-button")
  await target.click()

})();
```